# Xconnect Connection Issue

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore-xdb

```
"Message": "Operation failed: One or more dependencies failed",
  "ExceptionMessage": "One or more dependencies failed",
  "ExceptionType": "Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.DependencyFailedException",
  "StackTrace": null,
  "InnerException": {
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Store Error: Cannot open database \"espire_Xdb.Collection.ShardMapManager\" requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'espire_collectionuser'.. The error occurred while attempting to perform the underlying storage operation during 'Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.ElasticScale.ShardManagement.StoreException: Error occurred while performing store operation. See the inner SqlException for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database \"espire_Xdb.Collection.ShardMapManager\" requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'espire_collectionuser'.\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessTok
```

Update the user for that table and in xconnect webconfig

Answer (score 1):

Based on your error message, you are experiencing a login failure when connecting to your data store. Either your database is rejecting the connection, or you have the wrong credentials to access that database.

Since it seems to be SQL, you can try using SQL Management Studio and logging in directly with the credentials in your configuration file. If that doesn't work, then you will know it's the credentials that are the issue.

If the credentials are fine, then you need to look at why SQL Server might be rejecting your connection from your application. It might be that remote connections are not enabled, or that you have the wrong connection details for the SQL Server instance.